# Save dynamic html table data to database codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, dynamic-tables

Following is the portion in my view file.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Enter your Description" class="form-control name_list" required="" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter your Price" class="form-control name_list" required="" /></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

and this is my model

```
$query_status = $this->db->insert('events', $register_data_array);
    $event_insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();
    //insert the event ticket prices
    $price_description = $_POST['description'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    if ( ! empty($price_description) && ! empty($price) )
    {
        foreach ($price_description as $key => $value) {
            $data['event_id'] = $event_insert_id;
            $data['price_description'] = $value;
            $data['price'] = $price[$key];
            $this->db->insert('event_ticket_prices',$data[]);
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();
        return true;
    }
```

The insert_id is the last insert ID for the static information on the form. these gets saved without an issue, but for the dynamic tale I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer
Your insert is in the wrong place.
Move

```
$query_status = $this->db->insert('events', $register_data_array);
$event_insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();
```

after the foreach like this

```
foreach ($price_description as $key => $value) {
     $query_status = $this->db->insert('events', $register_data_array);
     $event_insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();
     $data['event_id'] = $event_insert_id;
     ...
```

And your other insert is wrong

```
$this->db->insert('event_ticket_prices',$data);
```

And that will fix your issues.

Note : You should always empty your `$data` array with each loop.  Assuming your `$data` array only has those 3 fields. Your `trans->complete` is also in an odd spot as if it fails, does your code still do a `trans->complete`?